# Error reading csv files from an URL in Markdown

Tags: r, csv, url, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to download some data from the bank of England website to do some charts. I  use read.csv as in the script below and this works fine when I run this in the R console.

```
    require(xts)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
url <-  "http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/JAN/1975&Dateto=now &SeriesCodes=XUDLUSG,XUDLERG&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y&VPD=Y&VFD=N"

datamat <- read.csv(url)
datamat <- na.omit(datamat)
rownames(datamat) <- as.Date(datamat$DATE,format = "%d %B %Y")
datamat <- datamat[,2:3]

datamat <- na.omit(as.xts(datamat))
chart.TimeSeries(datamat,main="")
```

however when I am trying to generate a report using markdown I get the following error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
>   Execution halted

The code I use is the same than above aside that it as the Markdown

````
```{r  getboedata }

require(xts)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
url <-  "http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/JAN/1975&Dateto=now &SeriesCodes=XUDLUSG,XUDLERG&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y&VPD=Y&VFD=N"

datamat <- read.csv(url)
datamat <- na.omit(datamat)
rownames(datamat) <- as.Date(datamat$DATE,format = "%d %B %Y")
datamat <- datamat[,2:3]

datamat <- na.omit(as.xts(datamat))
chart.TimeSeries(datamat,main="")


```
````

Comment: The first block of code isn't working for me.  `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: There's a space in your URL, right after `now` that's causing the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for this... you are right and it did the trick.. I really appreciate your help.